# Two level loop over a matrix's row in R

Tags: r, matrix, iteration

I need to convert the iteration below into matrix operation.

```
a = certain_matrix(3,5)
mat = matrix(0, 3,3)

for ( i in 1:3 )
  for ( j in 1:3 )
    mat[i,j] = certain_distance(a[i,], a[j,])
```

Roughly I need to use apply(). However, I cannot get hold of the row index in

```
apply(a, 1, function(x) XXX)
```

So how to perform that operation fast?

Comment: What's `certain_matrix`?

Comment: You problem seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18080568/1412059) I answered recently. However, there are some packages offering highly optimized functions for many distance measures.

Comment: @Thomas it's some lines of codes. returns a double

Comment: Soless - a "double" is a scalar.  Clearly `certain_matrix` is returning an **array** of doubles.  Meanwhile, how about rewriting your `certain_distance` function so it calculates all values rather than just the distance between two specified rows?

Comment: Try `mat <- outer(seq_len(nrow(a)), seq_len(nrow(a)), Vectorize(function(i, j)certain_distance(a[i, ], a[j, ]))`. We might be able to help further if you showed us what `certain_distance` looks like.

Comment: @flodel I don't think `outer` in combination with `Vectorize` (which basically is a call to `mapply`) is much better than the for loops. Using `combn` as demostrated in the question I linked to should do better.